Adding space in URLs variable
Server with PHP 7.1
I have a variable with an url:
$url = "https://mysite...";

When i try to use this url, the url becomes https: //mysite... (with a space after https:)
str_replace, sprintf or other methods are not working.
Using echo to print url, the result is the same (with space), but after first echo, it works good.
$url = "https://mysite...";
echo $url; //Output: https: //mysite...
echo $url; //Output: https://mysite...

I tried string replace, sprintf, exec getting output result, ecc..
Answer for the ADyson's comment: there is no code to paste in order to reproduce the problem.
The function starts with variable declaration and ends with some operations after echo.
function downloadStats2() {
    $url = 'https://example.com....';
    echo $url;

In development environment all works fine. In debug all works fine. It seems to be PHP problem on web server.
The website is configured with ISPConfig and the server is Debian.
It seems that variable just change its value in echo function.
In debug:


In production environment calling same function:

Edit: it seems that if i echoes 2 times same variable, first time is bad, second is ok.
This is my function:
private function saveProductsInfo($id) {
    $url = 'http://127.0.0.1/xxxxxx';

    echo "$url";
    echo "\n\n";
    echo "$url";
}

This is the result:


Please post a [mre] of the issue. What you've shown so far has no obvious problem - demo: https://3v4l.org/esmc4#v7.1.33 . You mention curl but then don't show any code regarding that. See also [ask] for tips on asking a good, answerable question. You can [edit] your post to update it. We'll be happy to help if you can post something which actually demonstrates the issue you're describing. Thanks.

If you can't provide anything which demonstrates the problem then a) how can anyone help you and tell you what code to fix, and b) how can you even prove there is a problem in the first place? If this behaviour is genuinely occurring then it must be traceable to something. Again, you mentioned you think it has something to do with curl, but did not explain further, or tell us anything else about that code. What further investigations have you done, specifically, which led you to make that remark?

If the variable doesn't contain space after https: then when you echo it should have no space. If there is space while the variables hasn't then it come from other process. You have to post the sample code start from variable until echo out and everyone can re-produce the same problem. Not just screenshots because it doesn't help anything.

it should.... on the screen you can see real function start

Nothing you've posted gives us any clues or reasons for what appears to be happening, unfortunately. You'll have to keep digging.

When you do the two echos, do you see the space in the first one in View Source?

yes @Bramar, i see it in preview tab in developer tools

Added another example.

"Server with PHP 7.1" - this server needs an update. Please keep in mind that the whole v7 branch is EOL since more than a year!

Also, there's no way that PHP will echo the exact same string differently when running the two echo calls line by line

Did you try looking at source code with a hexadecimal editor ? There could be a hidden char you entered with the keyboard, that is not taken in account by your text editor but is really present in your code.

I tried to show special chars viewing in vs code and i tried byte differences, echo htmlentities, different variables.. the result is the same, first echo bad, second ok.

Still not reproducible, sorry: https://3v4l.org/tRHHu
